# Where can I find high-precision cartographic data of French rural areas?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, openstreetmap

While [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org) is rather good for cartographic information (and rendered maps) in urban areas of France, it is rather unsatisfactory in rural areas (except in the area where I live, where I improved the map!) The IGN local maps (1 : 25,000) are the reference maps for these, and include a high level of cartographic details while covering all of France. They are  available online from the government-subsidized [Géoportail](http://www.geoportail.gouv.fr/accueil), but are not part of the data made available through the French government *open data* effort (list of data available detailed [here in French](http://www.data.gouv.fr/Producteurs/Institut-National-de-l-Information-Geographique-et-Forestiere)). In particular, while there exist an API to query information, it cannot be downloaded for offline use (as far as I am aware).

Where can I download high-precision cartographic data of France, with a good coverage of rural areas?

Comment: Could you make clearer what you target? I suppose it is something Géoportail does not offer, but what is it? Is it that Géoportail does not release machine-readable data?

Comment: @Vince Géoportail offers an API to query information, but no possibility to download machine-readable data for offline use. I have edited my question to make that clearer, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Data.gov provides geospatial data for areas around the world through NASA satellite imagery and other shared services.  You can search for mapping data in France or anywhere else at http://geo.data.gov/geoportal/.  You can also see a view of a new geospatial catalog on Data.gov below.

I've already entered the [parameters for France](http://geo.gov.ckan.org/dataset?q=&ext_location=&ext_bbox=-3.9990234375,42.5530802889558,7.822265625000001,50.14874640066278&ext_prev_extent=-7.734374999999999,39.977120098439634,11.6015625,52.10650519075632), so you can see the data available.  Just draw the bounding box where you need it to find any geospatial data that is available in that area.

Comment: Thanks for the link… there's no cartographic data listed on that site, unfortunately, so while it will be useful for other researches, it doesn't help for maps